# Why drawing a thousands of rectangles in C# PictureBox is much slower than in Java jPanel?

Tags: java, c#, winforms, jpanel, drawing

In my application I need to draw in a loop a grid of a thousands of rectangles and drawing performance is often important for visual effects. When I was working on the application like that in Java, I overrided `paintComponent` method in a following way:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)     
{
    super.paintComponent(g);            
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    rectanglesGrid.draw(graphics2D);
}
```

The `rectenglesGrid` class contains a 2D ArrayList of rectangles named `cellsGrid`. The `draw` method code looks very similar to the following code:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D graphics2D)
{
    for (ArrayList<Rectangle2D.Float> cells : cellsGrid) 
    {
        for (Rectangle2D.Float cell : cells) 
        {
            graphics2D.setPaint(someColor);
            graphics2D.draw(cell);
            graphics2D.fill(cell);
        }
    }       
}
```

To force jPanel repaint, I created my own `TimerTask` class and in a `run` method call `jPanel.repaint()`. Drawing rectangles in Java in this way is realy fast.

Now I'm trying to write similar application in C#. To paint rectangles I created a following EventHandler:

```
private void cellsGrid_pb_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    rectanglesGrid.Draw(e.Graphics);
}
```

Again the `rectanglesGrid` class contains 2D array of rectangles and draw method is similar to the Java one:

```
foreach(Rectangle[] cells in cellsGrid)
    foreach(Rectangle cell in cells)
    {
        pen.Color = brush.Color = someColor;
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, cell);
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, cell);
    }
```

To force PictureBox repaint I use `Timer` and in a `Tick` event handler call `pictureBox.Refresh()`. Drawing rectangles in C# in this way is much, much slower than in Java.

**I wonder why?** I don't think it's just because "Java applications run faster than C# ones"... **My code in C# is really similar to the Java one, I even use equivalent tools for drawing. How to improve performance of drawing in C# windows forms application?**

I have tried to set `DoubleBuffered` property of a Form to true, if it does matter.

---

**EDIT - better description of my problem**

I'w working on the project that visualises [cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). This means, that in fact I don't have 2D grid of rectangles, but 2D grid of cells. I keep those cells in the 2D array (or ArrayList in Java). This grid of cells is contained in class, say '`CellularAutomaton`'. Cells are structs consisting of `State` (enum), `Rectangle`, static fields with `Color` structure and method, that returns proper `Color` according to the cell state. Cells change their state in succeeding time steps in the `NextStep()` method within `CellularAutomaton` class. `CellularAutomaton` class also contains `Draw()` method, which takes `Graphics` instance as parameter. Here is exact code of this method in C#:

```
public void Draw(Graphics graphics)
{
    foreach(Cell[] cells in cellsGrid)
        foreach(Cell cell in cells)
        {
            pen.Color = brush.Color = cell.Color;
            Rectangle rectangle = cell.Rectangle;
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rectangle);
            graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rectangle);
        }
}
```

Java:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D graphics2D)
{
    for (ArrayList<Cell> cells : cellsGrid) 
    {
        for (Cell cell : cells) 
        {
            graphics2D.setPaint(cell.getColor());
            graphics2D.draw(cell.getRectangle());
            graphics2D.fill(cell.getRectangle());
        }
    }       
}
```

In C# in the timer tick event handler I call:

```
pictureBox.Refresh();
cellularAutomaton.NextStep();
```

In Java in the `run` method of the `TimerTask` class I call:

```
jPanel.repaint();
cellularAutomaton.nextStep();
```

`PictureBox` / `jPanel` repainting causes grid of cells to be redrawn (because I overriden paintComponent method in Java and wrote event handler for paint event in C#, as I had written earlier).

Sample parameters, for which Java code works much faster:
15k 5x5 rectangles and 1 millisecond interval between each repainting and `CellularAutomaton` updating.

The implementations of the `NextStep()` method are very similar in C# and Java, so I guess, that slowdown in C# is caused by drawing (To be sure, that drawing causes slowdown, I'll measure it later).

---

**UPDATE**

I measured, that the `NextStep()` works a bit faster in C#. However drawing 200 times 10k 5x5 rectangles from 2D array of `Cell` in `CellularAutomaton` class **in C# takes about 1.8 seconds**, while **in Java it takes about 300 millisecs**. So as I thought, the problem is that drawing in C# is much slower.

Comment: Doublebuffered must be set true for the control you draw on but for a pictureBox is is true by default. Do you want the drawing process to be visible? Btw: GDI+ is __really old__ compared to whatever works inside of Java, so I would not be surprised at all if it is slower.

Comment: Inherit from `Control`. Turn on `UserPaint`, `AllPaintingInWmPaint`, `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` in constructor. Override `OnPaint` and put drawing logic there.

Comment: @TaW No, I don't want the drawing process to be visible. I only want to display a final result of drawing all rectangles in a one go.

Comment: Not sure it's related to your performance problem, but consider using `Invalidate` vs `Refresh` in your Tick handler. The first is actually "mark the control as "to be redrawn" (which will happen in a following `WM_PAINT` message). See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/subhagpo/2005/02/22/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh/) for other details

Comment: Can you add some numbers? I can draw/fill 20k smallish rectangles in ca 70ms including two random to vary the colors calls per rectangle. Not slow imo, but of course you can't do a shading animation with it.. (btw: drawing and filling with the same color makes no sense. Leave out the Draw and it is down to 45ms here)

Comment: 20k of 5x5 renctangles is enough to see difference in speed in my case. So maybe drawing is not a cause of app slowdown...

Comment: @Darko Currently the question is not useful in this format, please post a [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TaW Of course each rectangle can be drawn in one of the few colors. Maybe I'll try to describe my problem in better way.

Comment: Yes, updating the question with more details what you want to achieve may help us helping you. Do include all numbers including the Timer Interval..

Comment: OK, there is no such thing a Timer.Interval of 1ms. It has a resolution of 15-25ms, so this is one surely one limitation. __For this kind of speed you need a different timer__; there are several. But of course nobody can see more than 16Hz, which may or may not matter.

Comment: @TaW After removed filling, drawing is about 2.5 times faster, but still much slower than in jPanel. See update under the question.

Comment: I can draw&fill 15k Rectangles in ca 150ms. But our hardware surly is different..

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Drawing on custom control isn't faster, than drawing on picture box. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing everything into an off screen Bitmap and then set that Bitmap as the Image of the PictureBox.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
{
    // draw rects
}

pb.Image = bmp;
```

**EDIT**

Try doing this with a path. Also **never** loop structs (like rects) using `foreach`, because it creates new instances of them.

```
// generate some random rects
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Rectangle(rnd.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width), rnd.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height), rnd.Next(1, pictureBox1.Width), rnd.Next(1, pictureBox1.Height)));
}

var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
using (var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
{
    path.AddRectangles(list.ToArray());
    g.FillPath(Brushes.Red, path);
    g.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
}

pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

**EDIT #2**

The following runs in less than 300ms in my system (without debugger attached):

```
private class Cell
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Rectangle Rectangle { get; set; }
}

private Cell[] cellsGrid;
private Random rnd = new Random();

// generate 100k random cells
private void btnNextStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cellsGrid = new Cell[100000];

    for (int i = 0; i < this.cellsGrid.Length; i++)
    {
        this.cellsGrid[i] = new Cell()
        {
            Color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next()),
            Rectangle = new Rectangle(rnd.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width), rnd.Next(0, pictureBox1.Height), rnd.Next(1, 5), rnd.Next(1, 5))
        };
    }

    this.DrawCells();
}


// draw them and measure time taken
private void DrawCells()
{
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    var bmp = new Bitmap(this.pictureBox1.Width, this.pictureBox1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black))
    using (var b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.cellsGrid.Length; i++)
        {
            b.Color = this.cellsGrid[i].Color;
            g.FillRectangle(b, this.cellsGrid[i].Rectangle);

            p.Color = this.cellsGrid[i].Color;
            g.DrawRectangle(p, this.cellsGrid[i].Rectangle);
        }
    }

    this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    MessageBox.Show((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Did you do the offscreen drawing in the ui or ina background thread?

Comment: Ina timer tick event handler, so I'm not sure what thread it is :)

Comment: @kagelos Drawing paths isn't much faster in my case. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Comment: @Darko it should be if you first add all the geometries in one path and call draw once. The code above runs in just a few milliseconds.

Comment: @kagelos Your code runs in a few milliseconds, but it draws "only" 5k rectangles and using single path. In my case I need to draw much more rectangles (e.g. 15k or even 60k). Moreover they can be drawn in one of the three colors (according to the cell state - see my updated question), so I have to group them by brush color into three lists, create three paths and draw them separately. The final result isn't much faster. E.g drawing 200 times 15k 5x5 rectangles separately takes ~2600 millisecs and using paths ~2400 millisecs.

Comment: @kagelos Man, my machine also runs it in ~300ms, but this code draws all rectangles just once. I need to draw them constantly in a loop (in a timer tick event handler) and my measured times are for drawing all rectangles from grid 200 times.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found to improve performance of drawing rectangles in a `PictureBox` is to group rectangles by the same brush color into arrays and use `Graphics.FillRectangles(Brush, Rectangle[])` method instead of filling each rectangle separately using `Graphics.FillRectangle(Brush, Rectangle)` method. This speeds up drawing twice in my case, when I usually have 3 different brush Color. However it's still three times slower than drawing each rectangle separately in `jPanel`.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.. On Java the drawing is blazing fast without any flickering, yet on C# using the exact same strategy and code it barely runs and flickers like hell. I enabled double-buffering, tried with picture box, panel or even drawing on the window itself and it still is slower than Java..